# mtc.network error "Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : factor level [5] is duplicated"

Tags: r, rjags, metafor

I have seen some similar problems to my query here but those solutions have not worked for me. I am trying to build a network meta-analysis and am encountering the following error after calling the **mtc.network** command:

```
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : factor level [5] is duplicated
```

My data are

```
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)

study<-c("Jones", "Jones", "Prieto", "Prieto", "Scott", "Scott", "Mickle", "Mickle", "Yang", "Yang", "Zhao", "Zhao")
n<-c(3886, 3876, 218, 214, 2040, 2014, 137, 137, 683, 683, 221, 230)
surv<-c(114, 94, 3, 8, 30, 20, 1, 4, 9, 11, 1, 2)
treat<-c("dx1", "px1", "rx1", "tx1", "rx1", "ax1", "zx1", "tx1", "gx1", "tx1", "ax1", "px1")

df<-data.frame(study, n, surv, treat)

network1<-mtc.network(data.ab=df, treatments=df$treat)
```

I then get this message

```
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [5] is duplicated
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in this.

Comment: In the documentation, it says the `treatments` as a data.frame with unique ids and description

Comment: Perhaps, consider changing the column names `names(df) <- c("study", "sampleSize", "responders", "treatment");network <- mtc.network(df, description="Example", treatments=unique(df$treatment))` and the output is `network#
MTC dataset: Example
Arm-level data:..`

Comment: @arkun thanks mate, seems to be working for the moment. Just got a little warning after calling ```mtc.network``` "Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated."

Comment: @Sandra That is because it is a tibble.  You can convert to `data.frame` with `df <- as.data.frame(df)` if you want to remove the warnings

Comment: `tibble` won't allow any row names.  It is just a friendly warning.

Comment: @akrun thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the function requires data to be formatted in a particular way. We could change the column names as in the example datasets and it would work

```
names(df) <- c("study", "sampleSize", "responders", "treatment")
network <- mtc.network(df, description="Example", treatments=unique(df$treatment))
```